# How do I make only the background image lighter or translucent and not the whole layout?

Tags: android

When I use  `android:alpha="0.4"` the whole layout becomes lighter. I just want the background image to get affected and not the text and other views over it.

[image: The text over it also becomes lighter.]

Comment: do you use `android:alpha="0.4"` on your top view container or on your ImageView?

Comment: please paste your `.xml` file

Comment: @ZUNJAE I have a parent scroll view with child linear layouts. I set the background image and alpha in the parent scroll view. 
(BTW we spoke on discord a couple hours ago regarding my content not showing up. :-)
My xml tag from this question was deleted.

Comment: Small world :p --- Changing the opacity of the parent scroll view will change the opacity of the children as well. What you could do is wrap everything in a FrameLayout (which adds views in the Z-axis), start with an ImageView (which is your background) then apply an alpha on the ImageView. The end result will look like `<FrameLayout><ImageView/><RelativeLayout>**THE REST OF THE VIEW HERE</RelativeLayout><FrameLayout>`

Comment: @ZUNJAE This solved my bug. Thank you. Need to check out FrameLayout more.